# "ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Visible = xlSheetVisible" doesn't work always

Tags: vba, excel

I have created 2 sheets. Sheet1 has the message

Now the code shud become hidden but this fails to happen always. Sometimes  remains visible and Sheet1 remains hidden. Why is it so?

sorry I forgot to mention one imp detail. The  sheet contains a button. When the button is pressed it brings up the input box. Now the problem is when I choose option 1 to view the list and then press the button and select option 4 and click on ok, it clses the workbook but it doesn't hide the tracker and make Sheet1 visible even after the changes u recommended. I have uploaded the sheet pls take a look thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the visible worksheet is **selected** before saving:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Visible = xlSheetVisible
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
                ws.Visible = xlVeryHidden
            End If
        Next ws
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I have modified my post. pls take a look... thanks